# How do I create a partitioned table without initial partitions?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl, database-partitioning

Say, I have the following DDL:

```
create table partition_test_table
(
    id number(38,0) not null,
    value varchar(255),
    country_code varchar(2) not null,
    creation_date date not null,
    constraint pk_partition_test_table primary key (id)
)
partition by range ( creation_date )
subpartition by list ( country_code );
```

This doesn't work because it doesn't declare any initial partitions. How do I create a partitioned table without initial partitions? Is that even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you need at least one partition.